# Cascade amplifier

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, analog, bjt

Consider a cascade amplifier. Usually, as the signal propagates through each stage the amplitude of the signal increases so subsequently, after a certain stage, doesn't it introduce non-linear behavior as the amplitude of the signal at that stage isn't within the limits (for example a BJT input V<sub>in</sub> <26mv (V<sub>t</sub>.) How can the overall-gain be the product of individual gain of each stage?

Are we limiting the signal amplitude at each stage? How can it act as an amplifier?

Comment: This is why we talk about "small signal" gain rather than large-signal gain (which suffers from distortion). Using small-signal analysis we can say that the overall gain is the product of the individual gains.

Comment: As @Andyaka said - you need to differentiate between small and large singal analysis. For a e.g. report you can also state: The gain is xABC for Uin [-Vmax,Vmax] for example. The reader will know: I get gain ABC as long as my signal is within this range - otherwise, i dont know what happens.

Comment: The signal level isn't taken into account when calculating the gain. You can overload a single stage if you put enough signal into it. When designing an amplifier you design it with the gain you'll need for the expected input and output levels, and often you design it with much more gain then you need and then use negative feedback to control it.

Comment: You design each stage of a multistage amplifier for the level you expect it to handle. So the first stage might be low noise, but have a small signal headroom, perhaps using a grounded emitter BJT stage. The second stage has to handle a higher signal level, so can afford to be noisier, and it might use a BJT stage with a resistor between emitter and ground, which linearises the response but introduces noise. Apply enough signal, any amplifier stage will overload. Keep the signal small, and the total gain will be the product of the gains of all the stages.

Comment: Can't we design the amplifier with one stage!

Comment: Sure if you can take μW to W!

Comment: @laksh Cascaded amplifiers is mostly old-school. Global NFB is usually critical, today. Yes, you can design an amplifier with one stage if the input and output requirements permit, or if your definition of "stage" is sufficiently flexible. Are you still confused about how "old-school" open-loop chained stages work?

Comment: @periblepsis yes!

Comment: @laksh You mention \$V_T\$ in your question. Why? In what sense do you mean to inject that topic into [cascaded amplifier systems](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zv5Zf.png)? (It's important for BJTs, as you suggest. But it has multiple meanings for amplifiers -- temperature stability for simple CE stage blocks or input range for differential stage blocks.)

Comment: @periblepsis Basically, for BJT's the input signal must be less than thermal voltage for linear operation, right? So, after amplification at the first stage the input voltage for the second stage wouldn't within  the limits, doesn't it introduce the non-linear behaviour!

Comment: @lakshmideepmaddineni That's "kind of" true for the differential (long-tailed pair) stage in the sense that the part of the arctangent curve that appears "linear" in slope is close to that range of differential voltage at the base. But this is more about opamps where both inputs are kept small with respect to each other using feedback and really doesn't have much to do with cascaded amplifiers.

Comment: @laksh [Here is part of page 167](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6ekL.png) from a book by Abraham Pressman called *"Switching and Linear Power Supply, Power Converter Design"* from 1977 (1st edition.) It shows what I mean by the "arctangent" curve and you can see the x-axis annotations in terms of \$V_T\$ there. (This was the first book I learned anything about power supply designs. Contrasting this book against newer editions (3rd, for example) tells you most of what you need to know about the sweeping changes that switchers have made in today's world. Trade-offs have changed dramatically.)

Comment: @laksh But again, this arctangent behavior is due to a pair of BJTs being used in a certain way. It has very little to do with cascaded amplifier stages. But you haven't written enough about what you imagine they are, so I'm projecting my own views onto the use of that phrase until/unless you write more about it.